# How to get parameter on ngClick. And then, triggered the directive to injected dinamically template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I need to inject new template dynamically depending on the value or parameter of radio button. 
This is my HTML

```
 <div class="container-fluid" ng-app="rjApp">
        <div class="panel-body" ng-controller="mainController"> 
             <input name="penanggung_biaya"  type="radio"  ng-model="checked"  ng-click="broadcast(umum)" class="ace" value="umum"> <!-- I though, umum is the parameter which I want passed through to the Controller   -->     
             <input name="penanggung_biaya"  type="radio" ng-model="checked" ng-click="broadcast(instansi)" class="ace" value="instansi"> 

<example-directive message="message"> </example-directive> 

       </div>
 </div>
```

and, this is the JS

```
   var rjApp = angular.module('rjApp',[]);
    rjApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
      $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{::');
      $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('::}');
    })


//mainCotroller, should be work by ngClick through radio button 
    function mainController($scope, $rootScope) { 
        $scope.broadcast = function(event){
        console.log(event) //I've been thought, this is the part to passing the parameter of radio button, but not gonna works.
            $rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast'); 
        };
    }


//the Directive, should be injected dinamically template, depends on ngClick parameter inside radion button  
    rjApp.directive('exampleDirective', function() {
        return {

            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                message: '='
            },
            link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
                scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function(doifq) {  
                    templateUrl= '<?php echo url("registrasi/rawat_jalan/penanggung_biaya/") ?>'+doifq //This is the part to injected the dinamically template. And I've been guess the **doifq**, is the paramter to passing by the mainController
                });                     
            },
        };
    });
```

Please, somebody help me. 

Regards.

Comment: do you want just to switch templates or restart your directive?

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon just switch the template. If I've choose the radio, and then, the templates are switching.

Answer (score 0):

```
In broadcast, you could pass the parameter, 
  $scope.broadcast = function(event){
        console.log(event);
        $rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast',event); 
  };
This way you would be getting doifq value in directive depending on the which radio button is clicked.
```

Comment: If I choosed radio button, I want get the parameter at the first. I want to see console.log return =  'umum' or 'instansi'.  But at now, console.log(event) // had return undefined

Comment: In ng-click pass value in string format. Here umum is undefined as a variable and hence in console it's returning undefined. Try ng-click="broadcast('umum')" and ng-click="broadcast('instansi')" respectively.

Comment: yes thats works in mainController, showed umum and instansi. But, how get that parameter in directive? how to passing that paramter to directive? Thanks.

Comment: In directive, inject rootScope and then register on event:  
rootScope.$on('handleBroadcast', function(doifq) {  
                    templateUrl= '<?php echo url("registrasi/rawat_jalan/penanggung_biaya/") ?>'+doifq 
                });

Comment: I'm sorry mister, I've dont get your point. 

 link: function(rootScope, elm, attrs) {
            rootScope.$on('handleBroadcast', function(doifq) {  
                console.log(doifq),
                templateUrl= '<?php echo url("registrasi/rawat_jalan/penanggung_biaya") ?>'+doifq 
            });                     
        },

isn't?

Comment: Yes, is your $on event listener getting called? If yes, then doifq variable would be having 'umum' or 'instansi' value.